# Files uploaded with Google Drive SDK not viewable

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have created a simple PHP script to play around with Google's Drive SDK. The plan is that eventually we will use Google Drive as a form of CDN for some of our web content (our company already has already upgraded to 1TB).

The code works to  a degree, in that it successfully authenticates and uploads a file. The problem is, the file is always broken and cannot be viewed either with Drive itself, or by downloading.

The code is relatively simple, and just fetches an image from Wikipedia and attempts an upload:

```
<?php

require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Drive.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Oauth2.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

//$client->setUseObjects(true);
//$client->setAuthClass('apiOAuth2');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));
$client->setClientId('***');
$client->setClientSecret('***');
$client->setRedirectUri('***');
$client->setAccessToken(authenticate($client));

// initialise the Google Drive service
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);


$data = file_get_contents('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_010.jpg');

// create and upload a new Google Drive file, including the data
try
{
    //Insert a file
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($client);

    $file->setTitle(uniqid().'.jpg');
    $file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    ));
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    print $e->getMessage();
}

print_r($createdFile);

?>
```

The `print_r` statement executes and we get information about the file. However, as I mentioned, the file is not viewable, and appears to be corrupt. Can anyone shed any light on what the issue may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more digging around in the docs (the current public docs are seriously out of date), I found that it's necessary to send another parameter as part of the `insert()` function's `body` parameter (the second argument in the function call).

Using the following:

```
$createdFile = $service->files->insert($doc, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'uploadType' => 'media',    // this is the new info
));
```

I was able to get everything working. I'll leave the question here, as I think it will be very useful until such a time that Google actually updates the documentation for the PHP API.

[**Source info here**](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok.
Have You tried to download this file from Google Drive afterwards and look at it? 
Also I know its abit stupid but have You tried to write file on disk right after using file_get_contents(). You know just to establish point where it goes bad for 100%.